# Disable text wrapping for each single line of a Text in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, string, swiftui, text

I want to display a long string consisting of multiple lines in a widget with a `Text` element. I don't know the amount of lines or the max. line length. The lines should not be wrapped so that each line in the text element should be actually a new line.

**Wanted behaviour:**

[image]

**Default behaviour:**

```
Text("1foofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoo\n2foofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoo\n3foofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoo")
```

[image]

Adding a `lineLimit` to the `Text` does not work as the limit applies to the entire text.

Splitting the string and creating for each line a new `Text` element with a `linieLimit` does not work for me because it would cause vertical overlapping in a widget as I don't know how many lines fit in the widget. So far, I have not been able to find a solution to clip the many `Text` elements with the help of `GeometryReader` to a fixed height & width.

Here is an example that shows the overlapping (line 1 and 9 is missing):
[image]

```
import SwiftUI
import WidgetKit

struct ExampleWidgetView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 3) {
            Text("1foofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoo")
            Text("2foofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoo")
            Text("3foofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoo")
            Text("4foofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoo")
            Text("5foofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoo")
            Text("6foofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoo")
            Text("7foofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoo")
            Text("8foofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoo")
            Text("9foofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoo")
        }
    }
}

struct ExampleWidgetView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ExampleWidgetView()
            .containerBackground(.clear, for: .widget)
            .previewContext(WidgetPreviewContext(family: .systemMedium))
    }
}
```

Using a horizontal `ScrollView` and therefore simply hiding the characters that are too much for the limited width does also not work as ScrollViews can't be used in widgets.

Comment: "because it would cause vertical overlapping in a widget as I don't know how many lines fit in the widget" Sounds like that is the problem you should be fixing. Please show a [mcve] of how it "would cause vertical overlapping".

Comment: I added an example. The uncertainty about the string's amount of lines is nothing I can change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say, splitting the string on newline characters and then using `.lineLimit(1)` on these substrings is the right approach.

You didn't explain how you wanted it to work when there are a lot of lines, but I am guessing you would like it to start with line 1 and any lines that don't fit in the vertical space are simply not shown.

So here is a version that works in this way. The text is shown in an overlay over a clear background, because this gives more control over the vertical alignment. The modifier `.minimumScaleFactor` allows a small degree of shrinkage, if necessary. This gets used when lines are very long, or when there are a lot of lines. If you wanted to allow more content to be squeezed into the display then you could make the factor smaller.

```swift
struct ExampleWidgetView: View {

    let veryLongStringWithLineBreaks = """
        1foofoofoofoo foofoofoofoofoo foofoofoofoofoo foofoofoofoofoo
        2foofoofoofoo foofoofoofoofoo foofoofoofoofoo foofoofoofoofoo
        3foofoofoofoo foofoofoofoofoo foofoofoofoofoo foofoofoofoofoo
        4foofoofoofoo foofoofoofoofoo foofoofoofoofoo foofoofoofoofoo
        5foofoofoofoo foofoofoofoofoo foofoofoofoofoo foofoofoofoofoo
        6foofoofoofoo foofoofoofoofoo foofoofoofoofoo foofoofoofoofoo
        7foofoofoofoo foofoofoofoofoo foofoofoofoofoo foofoofoofoofoo
        8foofoofoofoo foofoofoofoofoo foofoofoofoofoo foofoofoofoofoo
        9foofoofoofoo foofoofoofoofoo foofoofoofoofoo foofoofoofoofoo
        """

    var body: some View {
        Color.clear
            .overlay(alignment: .top) {
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 3) {
                    ForEach(veryLongStringWithLineBreaks.split(separator: "\n"), id: \.self) { line in
                        Text(line)
                            .lineLimit(1)
                            .allowsTightening(true)
                            .minimumScaleFactor(0.8)
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

[image: Widget]

---

*EDIT* Following up on your comment, a margin can be enforced at the bottom by using a `GeometryReader` to read the available height and clipping the content to this height. Like this:

```swift
var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { proxy in
        Group {
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 3) {
                ForEach(veryLongStringWithLineBreaks.split(separator: "\n"), id: \.self) { line in
                    Text(line)
                        .lineLimit(1)
                        .allowsTightening(true)
                        .minimumScaleFactor(0.8)
                }
            }
            .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
        }
        .frame(height: proxy.size.height, alignment: .top)
        .clipped()
    }
}
```

[image: Clipped]

You will notice that the `VStack` is nested inside a `Group`. This is so that the lines of text are shown in the middle when there are only a few lines, instead of being pushed to the top.

If you don't like the sharp cut-off either then one option would be to cover the bottom region with a gradient, so as to give a fade-out effect. Like this:

```swift
var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { proxy in
        Group {
            // content as above
        }
        .frame(height: proxy.size.height + 10, alignment: .top)
        .clipped()
        .overlay(alignment: .bottom) {
            Rectangle()
                .fill(
                    LinearGradient(
                        colors: [.clear, Color(UIColor.secondarySystemBackground)],
                        startPoint: .top,
                        endPoint: .bottom
                    )
                )
                .frame(height: 50)
        }
    }
}
```

[image: FadeOut]

However, the gradient is always there, so if the number of lines is exactly right to fill the vertical space, the last line will probably be under the gradient.

---

*EDIT2* Here is one more workaround for you. You could calculate how many lines will fit and only show this number. A `GeometryReader` can be used to deliver the available height, but you will probably need to make do with an estimate of the line height. However, this estimate could be defined as a `ScaledMetric`, so that it adapts automatically to different text size settings. Also, you will probably need to disable the automatic scaling that `.minimalScaleFactor` gives you, by not including this modifier.

Like this:

```swift
@ScaledMetric(relativeTo: .body) private var estimatedLineHeight: CGFloat = 20.3
private let spacing: CGFloat = 3

var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { proxy in
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: spacing) {
            ForEach(
                Array(veryLongStringWithLineBreaks.split(separator: "\n").enumerated()),
                id: \.offset
            ) { index, line in
                if (CGFloat(index + 1) * estimatedLineHeight) + (CGFloat(index) * spacing) < proxy.size.height {
                    Text(line)
                        .lineLimit(1)
                        .allowsTightening(true)
                }
            }
        }
        .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
}
```

[image: LimitedLines]

Comment: But it doesn't fix the overlap problem, right? There is no way to keep the same padding on the bottom edge as on the other edges?

Comment: Answer updated (again).