# How can I make sure words with symbols in them are not split between two lines in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, textview

I am using SwiftUI to display a `TextView`. The text it displays is "McDonnell Douglas F/A-18 Hornet. It includes a "/" in between two of its letters, "F" and "A". Right now, the text is being split in half, with the "McDonnell Douglas F/" on the first line and "A-18 on the second.

This is what is happening right now:

[image]

I want this:

[image]

My code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { g in
                Text("McDonnell Douglas \nF/A-18")
                    .font(.system(size: g.size.width * 1 / 20))
                    .frame(width: g.size.width / 2)
                    .border(.black)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Note: I am aware that `\n` can be used for line breaks, but that will not work for my case since the screen size will be different for different devices, and I don't know where the line break will be positioned. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Unicode character [U+FEFF ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE](https://unicode-explorer.com/c/FEFF) to say that there cannot be a line break.

```
Text("McDonnell Douglas F\u{FEFF}/\u{FEFF}A-18")
```

Use [`replacingOccurrences`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/stringprotocol/replacingoccurrences(of:with:options:range:)) or a [regex](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/rangereplaceablecollection/replacing(_:maxreplacements:with:)) to replace the characters you want, if the text is dynamic.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know what characters will need the unicode character to not be broken up? For example, do I need them around the hyphen too?

Comment: @Tiger I'm not sure but I think every word boundary can be broken up (?) Hyphens can definitely be broken up. If you don't want any line breaks, why not just `lineLimit(1)`? [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77234549/5133585) might also be relevant, though it has no answers.

Comment: The general algorithm is explained here: http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr14. The rules for `/` are somewhat intentionally ambiguous (see http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr14/#SY). Unfortunately, I don't know of any easy way to mark a section as unbreakable, except to inject FEFF between each pair of characters, which is certainly possible, but pretty obnoxious. It also has unfortunate impacts on copy-and-paste. I would probably solve this particular problem using two separate Texts in a VStack.